# Having problems with making my dark theme work using imagery

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm currently stuck on the following codes below. I've stayed up for the past two nights trying to figure it out but I need help, please. Currently working on my portfolio from scratch but I ended up with difficulties when I tried to implement a dark theme method within my code using dark and light images.

**themeContext.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { theDarkTheme, theLightTheme } from '../theme/theme';

import darkImage from '../assets/images/darkImage.jpg';

import lightImage from '../assets/images/lightImage.jpg';

export const ThemeContext = createContext()

function ThemeContextProvider(props) {
// eslint-disable-next-line
const \[theme, setTheme\] = useState('light');
const \[drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen\] = useState(false);
const \[isDark, setDark\] = useState(true);

    const setHandleDrawer = () => {
        setDrawerOpen(!drawerOpen)
    }
    
    
    const themeChange = () => {
        if (isDark) {
            setTheme(theLightTheme);
            setDark(false);
        } else {
            setTheme(theDarkTheme);
            setDark(true);
        }
    } 
    
    useEffect(() => {
      window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', e => onSelectMode(e.matches ? 'dark' : 'light'));
    
      onSelectMode(window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches ? 'dark' : 'light')
    
      return () => {
        window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').removeEventListener('change', () => {
        });
      }
    }, []);
    
    const onSelectMode = (theme) => {
      setTheme(theme)
      if (theme === 'dark')
        document.body.classList.add('dark-mode')
      else
        document.body.classList.remove('dark-mode')
    }
    
    const value = { theme, drawerOpen, setHandleDrawer, themeChange, isDark }
    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={value}>
            {props.children}
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
    )

}

export default ThemeContextProvider
```

**landing-ui.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { HashLink as NavLink } from "react-router-hash-link";
import Typed from 'react-typed';
import { greetings } from '../../data/portfolio';
import cartoon  from '../../assets/images/cartoon.png';

import darkImage from '../../assets/images/darkImage.jpg';

import lightImage from '../../assets/images/lightImage.jpg';

import { FaLinkedin, FaGithub } from 'react-icons/fa';
import '../../assets/css/landing.css';

function LandingUi ({ theme, drawerOpen, classes }) {

    return (
        <div className='landing' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${lightImage})`, backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat' }} >
            <div className='landing--container'>
                <div
                    className='social'
                    //style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${darkImage})`, backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat' }}
                >
                    <div className='lcl--content'>
                        {greetings.linkedin && (
                            <a
                                href={greetings.linkedin}
                                target='_blank'
                                rel='noreferrer'
                            >
                                <FaLinkedin
                                    className='landing--social linkedin-icon'
                                    style={{ color: theme.primary }}
                                    aria-label='LinkedIn'
                                />
                            </a>
                        )}
                        {greetings.github && (
                            <a
                                href={greetings.github}
                                target='_blank'
                                rel='noreferrer'
                            >
                                <FaGithub
                                    className='landing--social'
                                    style={{ color: theme.primary }}
                                    aria-label='GitHub'
                                />
                            </a>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img
                    src={cartoon}
                    alt=''
                    className='landing--img'
                    style={{
                        opacity: `${drawerOpen ? '0' : '1'}`,
                        borderColor: theme.primary,
                    }}
                />
                <div
                    className='landing--container-right'
                        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${darkImage})`, backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', backgroundSize: 'cover' }} >
    
                    <div
                        className='lcr--content'
                        style={{ color: theme.tertiary }}
                    >
                        {/* <h6 style={{ color: theme.primary }}>{headerData.title}</h6> */}
                        <span>Hello, I'm</span>
                        <h1>{greetings.name}</h1>
                        <Typed
                            strings={[
                                'WordPress Designer',
                                'Front End Designer']}
                            typeSpeed={40}
                            backSpeed={50}
                            className="typed-header"
                            style={{ color: theme.primary, fontSize: '20px' }}
                            loop
                        />
                        <div className='lcr-buttonContainer'>
                            {greetings.resumePdf && (
                                <a
                                    href={greetings.resumePdf}
                                    download='resume'
                                    target='_blank'
                                    rel='noreferrer'
                                >
                                    <button className={classes.resumeBtn}>
                                        Download CV
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            )}
                            <NavLink
                                to='/#contacts'
                                smooth={true}
                                spy='true'
                                duration={2000}
                            >
                                <button className={classes.contactBtn}>
                                    Contact
                                </button>
                            </NavLink>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}

export default LandingUi;
```

**theme-change.js**

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import React, { useContext} from "react";
import { BsFillMoonFill, BsFillSunFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { ThemeContext } from '../context/themeContext';
import './theme-change.css';

const ThemeChange = () =\> {
const { theme, themeChange, isDark } = useContext(ThemeContext);

    const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    
        icon: {
            fontSize: '1.5rem',
            color: theme.buttonColor,
            '&hover': {
                transform: 'scale(1.08)',
                color: theme.tertiary,
            },
        },
    }));
    
    const classes = useStyles();
    
    return (
        
        <div
            className="themeChange"
        >
    
            <button onClick={themeChange} aria-label="Back to top">
    
                {isDark ?
                    <BsFillSunFill className={classes.icon} />
                    :
                    <BsFillMoonFill className={classes.icon} />
                }
            </button>
    
        </div>
    );

};

export default ThemeChange;
```

**theme.js**

```
//import { darkTheme } from '../themeImg'
import darkImage from '../assets/images/darkImage.jpg';
//import { lightTheme } from '../themeImg';
import lightImage from '../assets/images/lightImage.jpg';

export const theLightTheme = {
type: 'light',
primary: '#1D9BF0',
quaternary: '#EFF3F4',
quaternaryLight: '#F7F9F9',
secondary: '#ffffff',
tertiary: '#0f1419',
buttonColor: '#0F1419',
lightImg: `(${lightImage})`
}

export const theDarkTheme = {
type: 'dark',
primary: '#1D9BF0',
secondary: '#0F0C41',
quaternary: '#0C0B33',
quaternaryLight: '#8b98a5',
tertiary: '#EFF3F4',
buttonColor: '#8B98A5',
darkImg: `(${darkImage})`
}
```

**landing.css**

```
.dark-mode .landing {
height: 700px;
background-position: top;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
justify-content: center;
background: url('../images/darkImage.jpg') no-repeat;
}

.landing--container {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

.landing--img {
\--img-size: 250px;
position: absolute;
right: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
width: var(--img-size);
height: var(--img-size);
object-fit: cover;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
transition: opacity 0.3s, filter 1s ease-in;
\-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.landing--img:hover {
\-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.social {
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
top: 35%;
}

.lcl--content {
padding: 10px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-evenly;
flex-direction: column;
}

.landing--social {
font-size: 35px;
margin: 15px;
transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.landing--social:hover {
transform: scale(1.2);
}

.landing--container-right {
flex: 65%;
height: 100%;
background: url('../images/lightImage.jpg') no-repeat;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-end;
justify-content: center;
background-size: cover;
}

.lcr--content {
width: 45%;
margin-right: 7rem;
font-family: var(--primaryFont);
font-style: normal;
}

.lcr--content span {
font-size: 30px;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-bottom: 15px;
font-family: "superiortitle", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.lcr--content h1 {
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 2.25rem;
line-height: 110%;
margin: 1rem 0;
}

.lcr-buttonContainer {
margin-top: 2rem;
width: 350px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
font-family: "var(--primaryFont)", sans-serif;
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
.landing--img {
\--img-size: 350px;
}
.lcl--content {
margin: 0rem;
}

    .lcr--content span {
        display: block;
    }
    .lcr--content h1 {
      font-size: 3rem;
    }
    
    .lcr-buttonContainer {
      margin-top: 1rem;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 200px;
      height: 120px;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
.landing--img {
\--img-size: 300px;
}

    .landing--social {
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    .lcr--content {
      width: 60%;
      margin-top: 10%;
      margin-right: 6%;
    }
    
    .lcr-buttonContainer {
      margin-top: 1rem;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 200px;
      height: 120px;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }
    .lcr-buttonContainer button:nth-child(2) {
      display: none;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
.landing--container {
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
}
.landing--img {
\--img-size: 200px;
left: 50%;
top: 30%;
border: 8px solid #eaeaea;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.social {
flex: initial;
width: 100%;
height: 30%;
}
.landing--social {
display: none;
}
.landing--container-right {
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0 2rem;
flex: initial;
height: 70%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #eaeaea;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
padding: 0 2rem;
}
.lcr--content {
margin-top: 20%;
margin-right: initial;
width: 100%;
}
.lcr--content .typed-header {
display: block;
font-size: 1rem;
text-align: center;
}
.lcr--content h1 {
font-size: 2.5rem;
text-align: center;
}

    .lcr-buttonContainer {
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .lcr-buttonContainer button {
      margin-top: -20%;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
.lcr--content {
margin-top: 35%;
}
}

@media (max-width: 370px) {
.lcr--content {
margin-top: 60%;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {
.landing {
height: 100%;
}

    .landing--img {
      --img-size: 150px;
      left: 50%;
      top: 20%;
    }
```

}

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Navigate, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import { ThemeContext } from './context/themeContext';
import Home from './pages/home/home';
import ThemeChange from './helper/theme-change';

import darkImage from './assets/images/darkImage.jpg';
function App() {

return (
//\<div style={{ backgroundColor: theme.secondary}}\>

    <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${darkImage})`, backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', backgroundSize: 'cover' }} >
      
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} exact />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <ThemeChange />
    </div>

);
}

export default App;
```

I've researched more on creating a dark theme using image instead of just colors. What I found help a little but confused me because it was something different.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).